# Do variables also get updated on rerender triggered by state change?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state change which causes rerender of my functional component. I have noticed the variables (let, var) sometime get updated and sometime do not, which are displayed on my DOM. Are updated value of variables picked up on rerender triggered by state. Can i use state for rerender trigger and then just variables for changes as it removes overhead of keeping everything in state? Or variables maintain their initial value at the time of mount?

For example doing this on Onclick event -

```js
  let display;
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  ...

  OnClick () =>{
    setState(newvalue);
    display = newdisplay;
  }

  ...

  // In DOM

  return (
    <div>
      {state}
      {display}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables are already updated before state change but rerendering the page just shows your changes, so if it's not updating it probably means you are setting state before you change the variable.

Also, don't set state within the return of your render function, that may also cause problems when it comes to DOM updates.

**Example of what you should do:**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myStateVariable: "I'm in state"
  };

  myVariable = "Something cool"; // This variable is accessible from anywhere in your component using 'this'

  updateVars = () => {
    this.myVariable = "Something else thats cool";
    this.setState({ myStateVariable: "I was now changed" });
  }

  render() {
    let myLocalVariable = "Locally grown"; // This variable is only accessible within your render function
    console.log(myLocalVariable);
    myLocalVariable = "I was locally grown"; // Changing the variable
    return (
      <>
        <p>{this.state.myStateVariable} is within state</p>
        <p>{this.myVariable} will not update its self</p>
        <p>{myLocalVariable} will always stay the same</p>
        <button onClick={this.updateVars}>Click Me</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for posting your question, I hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: OP's code uses functional components, so your answer isn't entirely applicable.